# L is decidable. Prove that “similar” language is also decidable

Tags: computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

Assume that $L$ is decidable. Is the following language decidable? $$ L' = \{w \mid \text{there is } u \in L \text{ such that $u$ and $w$ are equal to at most two positions.}\}$$

For example, let $u=abcd$. The following words are equal to $u$ at most two positions: $\{aba, agg, ab, zzz, dsa, \ldots\}$, but not $\{ abc, zbcd \}$

My approach:

> A language is decidable iff some enumerator enumerates the language in
>   lexicographic order.

I use above theorem.

So, $L$ is decidable. Therefore, let's take enumerator $E$ for it. Let We construct a $TM'$ for $L'$. Let enumerator $E$ be connected to $TM'$. For every input $w$ given to $TM'$ the $TM'$ compare it position by position with every string $v$ generated by $E$ in lexicographical order till $|v|\le|w|$ 
If number of the same positions $>2$ reject $w$. Otherwise, accept.

Ok?

Comment: It's ok, but you really need to replace 'lexicographic order' everywhere by 'military order' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortlex_order

Comment: Cross-posted: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/71772/755, http://math.stackexchange.com/q/2194238/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct . . . *if* you have a bound on the length of $u$ (that is, $u$ has to be no longer than $w$). However, the definition looks like it doesn't include this: e.g. it seems that if $ab\in L$ then $abcccccccccc$ would be in $L'$. If this is the case, it's not hard to show that $L'$ is not decidable.

Comment: you obviously right, but I cannot see how to prove that it is undecidable, please hint me.